# Number of ways to choose 4 groups of 4 people from a set of 16 people

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to choose 4 groups of 4 people each from a set of 16 people (the groups are distinct) ?
I can't quite decide if the answer should be ${16 \choose 4} + {12 \choose 4} + {8 \choose 4} + {4 \choose 4}$ or if it should be 
${16 \choose 4} \cdot {12 \choose 4} \cdot {8 \choose 4} \cdot {4 \choose 4}$

Can somebody give an intuitive explanation?

Comment: Sometimes it helps to think about a smaller version of the problem:  If you are choosing $2$ (distinct) groups of $2$ people from a set of $4$ people, is the answer ${4\choose2}+{2\choose2}=6+1=7$ or ${4\choose2}\cdot{2\choose2}=6\cdot1=6$?

Comment: You add only when the numbers being added represent *mutually exclusive outcomes* and we want to count them separately.  $|A|+|B|=|A\cup B|$ iff $A\cap B=\emptyset$.  You multiply when each number represents the number of choices available in a string of steps used for a multiplication principle argument.  $|A|\cdot |B| = |A\times B|$.  Here, you need to multiply not add.

Comment: You state the groups are distinct, which I at first interpreted to mean they are disjoint. Is that correct? Or do u mean the groups are distinct as in the identical partitioning into groups but in the different order, is distinct, I.e. it matters whether some set of 4 people is sent to group A, B, C, or D? If so, I presume they must also be disjoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are four groups, $A,B,C,D$

Obviously, group $A$ can be formed in $\binom{16}4$ ways.

For *each* way that group $A$ has been formed,
group $B$ can be formed from the remaining $12$ in $\binom{12}4$ ways, and so on.

So the multiplication rule is applicable, and we get $\binom{16}4\binom{12}4\binom84\binom44$

[The last term can be omitted, as whichever $4$ remain, automatically form the last group. ]

---

You would do well to review a simple exposition of probability rules [here](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch05-rul.html)

Note that the *general* multiplication rule is applicable for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have 16 chairs fixed in a row and you command 16 people to take a chair each. The first four chairs will make up the first group and so on. Now, we have $16!$ ways to sit the 16 people. But within each group, order doesn't matter, there are $4!$ ways that determine the same group.

Hence, the number you're looking for is

$$\frac{16!}{4! 4! 4! 4!}$$